# Setting user specific permissions on Apigee

Tags: user-permissions, apigee

I am trying to figure out how best to implement my project on Apigee platform. What seems like it would be the easiest option would require me to set user-specific permissions to allow access to particular entries in the database. At the first glance it would seem that it should be possible on Apigee, because permissions are set for "paths", and each data entry has its own path. In fact I am able to set such specific permissions for a role (like "Default"). However, when I select a particular user, go to "Roles & Permissions", and try to add this same specific permission, I get an error "Please match the requested format". It doesn't give me any more info than that, so I can't figure out what the issue is. I also realized that I can't set even a simpler permission for a user (like PUT for "//books/").
Please help me figure out what's going on. Thanks!

For example, I tried to use the path "/books/a93cc1ca-7c86-11e3-9d0f-29390a4673d8", which I get from this screen:
[image: data entry]

When I put it into the user's add permission dialog I see the following:
[image: error in dialog]

Comment: Please provide examples of *what* you're trying to set for permissions. Possibly provide a screenshot?

Comment: Please see improved question :)

Comment: Looks pretty broken to me! That should work. So should simply `/books`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try without the preceding '/' at the beginning.

That is just

```
books/a93cc1ca-7c86-11e3-9d0f-29390a4673d8
```

in place of

```
/books/a93cc1ca-7c86-11e3-9d0f-29390a4673d8
```

Comment: Wow, that works!!! Great call! Although I'd say that Apigee guys need to make some improvements there.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, Santanu is correct.  The field requires a / at the beginning, but this is a poor user experience. We will get this corrected in the next release.